# onclick function not working with internet explorer 11 but works fine with Chrome,Edge and Firefox and the date filter cannot give me my actual values

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function LoadCustomers() {
  var vinput = document.getElementById("searchInput").value;
  var vinput0 = document.getElementById("agencyid").value;
  var varConferenceStartDate = document.getElementById("startdate").value;
  var varConferenceEndDate = document.getElementById("enddate").value;
  var vcountry = document.getElementById("agerbet").value;
  var startDate = varConferenceStartDate.split("/").reverse();
  var tmp = startDate[2];
  startDate[2] = startDate[1];
  startDate[1] = tmp;

  startDate = startDate.join("-");

  var endDate = varConferenceEndDate.split("/").reverse();
  var tmp2 = endDate[2];
  endDate[2] = endDate[1];
  endDate[1] = tmp2;

  endDate = endDate.join("-");

  var dateTimeString = startDate + "T00:00:00.000Z";
  var dateTimeStringEnd = endDate + "T00:00:00.000Z";

  console.log(dateTimeString);

  var testErmi;

  var startTime = "datetime" + "'" + dateTimeString + "'";
  var endTime = "datetime" + "'" + dateTimeStringEnd + "'";

  let newTime = new Date(varConferenceStartDate);

  console.log(typeof varConferenceStartDate);
  console.log(typeof startDate);
  console.log(typeof startTime);

  if (
    varConferenceEndDate === null ||
    varConferenceEndDate === "" ||
    varConferenceStartDate === null ||
    varConferenceStartDate === ""
  ) {
    testErmi =
      "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('ConferenceIDRequest')/items?" +


      "$select=Title,ConferenceStartDate,ConferenceEndDate,NameofAgency,Country/CountryName&$expand=Country&$filter= substringof('" +
      vinput +
      "',Title)  or substringof('" +
      vinput0 +
      "',NameofAgency) or substringof('" +
      vcountry +
      "',Country/Country)";
  } else {
    testErmi =
      "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('ConferenceIDRequest')/items?" +
      "$select=Title,ConferenceStartDate,ConferenceEndDate,NameofAgency,Country/CountryName&$expand=Country&$filter= (ConferenceStartDate lt " +
      startTime +
      ") and (ConferenceEndDate gt " +
      startTime +
      ") or substringof('" +
      vinput +
      "',Title)  or substringof('" +
      vinput0 +
      "',NameofAgency) or substringof('" +
      vcountry +
      "',Country/CountryName)";
  }
  var call = $.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + testErmi,

    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
  });
  call.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
      data.d.results[i].ConferenceStartDate = new Date(
        data.d.results[i].ConferenceStartDate
      ).toLocaleDateString();
      data.d.results[i].ConferenceEndDate = new Date(
        data.d.results[i].ConferenceEndDate
      ).toLocaleDateString();
    }
    $("#example").dataTable({
      bDestroy: true,
      bProcessing: true,
      aaData: data.d.results,
      aoColumns: [{
          mData: "Title"
        },
        {
          mData: "NameofAgency"
        },
        {
          mData: "Country.CountryName"
        },
        {
          mData: "ConferenceStartDate"
        },
        {
          mData: "ConferenceEndDate"
        },
      ],
    });
  });
  call.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("Error retrieving Tasks: " + jqXHR.responseText);
  });
  return call;
}
</script>
```

My code is working fine in Google Chrome, Edge and Mozilla Firefox. But when it comes to internet explorer, when ever the button is click, it gave me an error in the console that loadCustomers is not defined. My date filter is also not  filtering the date values I am looking, it just gate all the dates less that the start date and those dates greater that the end dates

Comment: The name of the function is `LoadCustomer`, not `loadCustomers` -- JS is case-sensitive. But that should fail the same on all browsers. What is the exact error message?

Comment: Show how you're attaching the onclick function?

Comment: @Barmar I am getting error SCRIPT5009:'LoadCustomers' is undefined

Comment: @Barmar <input type="button" value="Get Customers" onclick="LoadCustomers();" />

Comment: If you put `console.log()` calls before and after the function definition, do you see them?

Comment: I see  them from Chrome and Edge not from internet explorer

Comment: Something is preventing your entire `<script>` tag from being loaded in IE, there's no way to tell why from what you've posted.

Comment: If you remove the entire function definition and just put `console.log("Script loaded")` do you see that?